# Loop a value into function and save the results in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, graph

I am working with a python package called ["cdindex"](https://github.com/russellfunk/cdindex) that gets data in network/graph structure (nodes and edges) and after creating a graph, it generates some integer properties of the nodes.

Following the package example, I have created the nodes (here vertices) and edges data as follows:

```
>>> $ pip install cdindex
>>> import cdindex
>>> import datetime

>>> # dummy vertices for python module tests
>>> pyvertices= [{"name": "0Z", "time": datetime.datetime(1992, 1, 1)},
                 {"name": "1Z", "time": datetime.datetime(1992, 1, 1)},
                 {"name": "2Z", "time": datetime.datetime(1993, 1, 1)},
                 {"name": "3Z", "time": datetime.datetime(1993, 1, 1)},
                 {"name": "4Z", "time": datetime.datetime(1995, 1, 1)},
                 {"name": "5Z", "time": datetime.datetime(1997, 1, 1)},
                 {"name": "6Z", "time": datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 1)},
                 {"name": "7Z", "time": datetime.datetime(1999, 1, 1)},
                 {"name": "8Z", "time": datetime.datetime(1999, 1, 1)},
                 {"name": "9Z", "time": datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 1)},
                 {"name": "10Z", "time": datetime.datetime(1997, 1, 1)}]

>>> # dummy edges for python module tests
>>> pyedges = [{"source": "4Z", "target": "2Z"},
               {"source": "4Z", "target": "0Z"},
               {"source": "4Z", "target": "1Z"},
               {"source": "4Z", "target": "3Z"},
               {"source": "5Z", "target": "2Z"},
               {"source": "6Z", "target": "2Z"},
               {"source": "6Z", "target": "4Z"},
               {"source": "7Z", "target": "4Z"},
               {"source": "8Z", "target": "4Z"},
               {"source": "9Z", "target": "4Z"},
               {"source": "9Z", "target": "1Z"},
               {"source": "9Z", "target": "3Z"},
               {"source": "10Z", "target": "4Z"}]
```

Next, I created the graph and added the nodes (here vertices) and edges to it:

```
>>> # create graph
>>> graph = cdindex.Graph()

>>> # add vertices
>>> for vertex in pyvertices:
      graph.add_vertex(vertex["name"], cdindex.timestamp_from_datetime(vertex["time"]))

>>> # add edges
>>> for edge in pyedges:
      graph.add_edge(edge["source"], edge["target"])
```

The code runs nicely, and I am able to initiate the "graph.cdindex" function to get a node's (in example case 4Z) *cdindex* as an integer value in output (i.e. 0.833).

```
>>> graph.cdindex("4Z", int(datetime.timedelta(days=1825).total_seconds()))
[Out] 0.8333333333333333
```

**My question**

I want to learn how I can loop multiple values to the "graph.cdindex" function and save the results in data frame. Technically, instead of "4Z" string value in the above function, I want to loop a column of many other string values (0Z, 1Z, 2Z, ...) and save their associated *cdindex* value in a new column.

**Deliverable**

A dataframe of all nodes (Node_Name) and their *cdindex* value (cdindex_Value) like below:

```
+-----------+---------------+
| Node_Name | cdindex_Value |
+-----------+---------------+
| 0Z        | 0.247         |
+-----------+---------------+
| 1Z        | 0.654         |
+-----------+---------------+
| 2Z        | -0.547        |
+-----------+---------------+
| 3Z        | 0.0           |
+-----------+---------------+
| 4Z        | 0.8333        |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to get all of the vertices and associated cindex values:

```
tuples = [(v, graph.cdindex(v, int(datetime.timedelta(days=1825).total_seconds()))) for v in graph.vertices()] # check how to get the vertices name

df = DataFrame(tuples, columns=['node', 'cindexvalue'])
```

Comment: I get an error "TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable".

Comment: ok, vertices is a function. Use `.vertices()` instead of `.vertices`. I have modified the code accordingly. Note that I have never used this library. Not sure if you will get an iterable of vertices names or the an iterable of vertex objects.

Comment: Thanks now it worked for the example with few number of nodes! I am running the code now for 7 million record vertices and already been 3 hours the code is running. Is it normal? Or any suggestion how to deal with it in such scale? Much appreciated your attention already!

Comment: Get the timing to extract one vertex property using timeit. You will be able to determine if this is the cause.

Comment: You can alternatively use networkx library.

Comment: Did you resolve the performance issue? I am curious to know.

Comment: For each node it takes 8ms and for creating the tuple (all 7million nodes) took almost 17 hours to run. As I have no other way to get the same results for benchmarking, I accepted your solution as it brilliantly worked, and I was just patient! :)

Comment: Try networkx library. 8ms is a crazy amount of time.